# Cypress how to test the value returned by a react custom hook

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, next.js, cypress

I do use a custom hook to read QrCodes and i'd like to implement a Component testing with Cypress.

My problem is that I don't have any DOM element to get the value from. It's just a hook which treat the decoded text the way I ask it to do

How could I get the value returned by my hook and verify it's the value i am expecting?

Here is my component calling the hook :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { QrCodeReaderProps } from "../types";

import useQrCodeScan from "./hooks";
import { styles } from "./styles";

export const QrCodeReader: React.FC<QrCodeReaderProps> = ({
  qrCodeNodeId,
  onScanSuccess,
  onScanError,
}) => {
  const { startQrScan } = useQrCodeScan({
    qrCodeNodeId: qrCodeNodeId,
    onScanSuccess: onScanSuccess,
    onScanError: onScanError,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    //start scanner on Mounting component
    startQrScan();
  }, [startQrScan]);

  return (
    <div
      className="rounded-xl overflow-hidden"
      style={styles.container}
      id={qrCodeNodeId}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

And here is the Hook :

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { Html5Qrcode, Html5QrcodeSupportedFormats } from "html5-qrcode";

import { useQrCodeScanProps } from "../types";

type DecodedQRData = {
  isScanning: boolean;
  isScanSuccess: boolean;
  isScanFailure: boolean;
  data: any;
  error?: string | any;
};

export default function useQrCodeScan({
  qrCodeNodeId = "",
  closeAfterScan = false,
  onScanSuccess,
  onScanError,
}: useQrCodeScanProps) {
  const scanZone = 300;
  const config = useMemo(
    () => ({
      rememberLastUsedCamera: true,
      qrbox: {
        width: scanZone,
        height: scanZone,
      },
      fps: 20,
      showTorchButtonIfSupported: true,
    }),
    [],
  );
  const html5QRCodeConfig = useMemo(
    () => ({
      formatsToSupport: [
        Html5QrcodeSupportedFormats.QR_CODE,
        Html5QrcodeSupportedFormats.EAN_13,
        Html5QrcodeSupportedFormats.EAN_8,
      ],
      verbose: false,
      useBarCodeDetectorIfSupported: true,
      experimentalFeatures: {
        useBarCodeDetectorIfSupported: true,
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  const [decodedQRData, setDecodedQrData] = useState<DecodedQRData>({
    isScanning: false,
    isScanSuccess: false,
    isScanFailure: false,
    data: null,
    error: "",
  });

  const QrScannerRef = useRef<Html5Qrcode | null>(null);
  const previousScan = useRef<string>("");

  const stopQrScan = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      if (QrScannerRef.current && QrScannerRef.current.isScanning) {
        QrScannerRef.current
          ?.stop()
          ?.then((ignore) => console.log("scan terminé - arrêt du scanner"))
          ?.catch((err) =>
            console.log("Impossible d'arrêter le scanner après un scan"),
          );
        previousScan.current = "";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("error while stopping scanner", e);
    }
  }, [QrScannerRef]);

  const startQrScan = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      setDecodedQrData((prevDecodedQRData) => ({
        ...prevDecodedQRData,
        isScanning: true,
        data: null,
      }));
      if (!QrScannerRef.current) {
        QrScannerRef.current = new Html5Qrcode(qrCodeNodeId, html5QRCodeConfig);
      }
      QrScannerRef.current
        .start(
          { facingMode: "environment" },
          config,

          (qrCodeData) => {
            if (qrCodeData !== previousScan.current) {
              onScanSuccess(qrCodeData);
              previousScan.current = qrCodeData;
              setTimeout(() => (previousScan.current = ""), 4000);
            }

            if (closeAfterScan && QrScannerRef.current) {
              QrScannerRef.current
                .stop()
                .then((ignore) =>
                  console.log("scan terminé - arrêt du scanner"),
                )
                .catch((err) =>
                  console.log("Impossible d'arrêter le scanner après un scan"),
                );
            }
          },
          (errorMessage) => {
            if (errorMessage.endsWith("The source width is 0.")) {
              console.log(
                "scanner crashed - try to restart the qrcode scanner",
              );
              stopQrScan();
              QrScannerRef.current = null;
            }
          },
        )
        .catch((err) => {
          onScanError(err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      setDecodedQrData((prevDecodedQRData) => ({
        ...prevDecodedQRData,
        isScanSuccess: false,
        isScanning: false,
        isScanFailure: true,
        data: null,
        error: err || "Lecture du QR code impossible",
      }));
    }
  }, [
    qrCodeNodeId,
    closeAfterScan,
    config,
    html5QRCodeConfig,
    onScanError,
    onScanSuccess,
    QrScannerRef,
    stopQrScan,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => stopQrScan, [stopQrScan]);

  return {
    startQrScan,
    decodedQRData,
    stopQrScan,
  };
}
```